# Transform html to xml with javascript (on kml files)

Tags: javascript, xml, kml, pentaho

i'm working with KML files (which actually are XML files used by google earth).
I'm trying to transorm these files and store in hbase. I've done these using pentaho kettle that is an ETL software and everything works fine.
I just have an issue. To better explain i'll show you a piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd">
   <Document>
      <name>operepubbliche:lavori_p_incorso,operepubbliche:lavori_l_incorso,operepubbliche:lavori_a_incorso</name>
      <Document xmlns:atom="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
         <name>operepubbliche:lavori_p_incorso</name>
         <LookAt>
            <longitude>11.242125039520602</longitude>
            <latitude>43.78113692504396</latitude>
            <altitude>14778.996010943278</altitude>
            <range>11942.2039598685</range>
            <tilt>0.0</tilt>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
         </LookAt>
         <Placemark id="lavori_p_incorso.1006">
            <name><![CDATA[lavori_p_incorso.1006]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[<h4>lavori_p_incorso</h4>

<ul class="textattributes">
  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">CODOPERA</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">90010</span></li>
  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">NOMEPROGETTO</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">COMPLETAMENTO DEI LAVORI DI RIQUALIFICAZIONE ARCHITETTONICA E FUNZIONALE DEL VOLUME EX FABBRI NELLAMBITO DELLEDIFICIO DENOMINATO  EX SCUDERIE ALLE CASCINE </span></li>
  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">NOTEPROGETTO</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Lavori svolti in Via: Piazzale delle Cascine Localita: Firenze Comune: Firenze Quartiere: 1.</span></li>
  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">AREATEMATICA</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Cultura</span></li>

  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">DATAINIZIO</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">7/11/11 12:00 AM</span></li>


</ul>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
               <longitude>11.21855371841724</longitude>
               <latitude>43.78316840442614</latitude>
               <altitude>0.0</altitude>
               <range>0.0</range>
               <tilt>0.0</tilt>
               <heading>0.0</heading>
               <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <Style>
               <IconStyle>
                  <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                  <Icon>
                     <href>http://datigis.comune.fi.it/img/helmet-2_s.png</href>
                  </Icon>
               </IconStyle>
               <LabelStyle>
                  <color>00ffffff</color>
               </LabelStyle>
            </Style>
            <Point>
               <coordinates>11.218553718417242,43.783168404426156</coordinates>
            </Point>
     </Document>
</kml>
```

As you can see in the description tag is contained something that seems HTML code.
I woluld like to tranform what's inside of description to an XML code as well.
I mean i would like to have all tags inside of description knowable by Pentaho Kettle to use those as field on my transformation.
Any ideas?
I need to do this with javascript so i can put the cod in Pentaho Kettle (which i think is the only way to do that).

Comment: PDI has XML input steps as well, such as the StAX step, Get data from XML, and XML Join. See what those will do for you. As far as translating HTML to XML, you probably do need JavaScript for that. Remember that PDI's JavaScript interpreter is Rhino, so you can use pure Java classes as well.

Comment: I know PDI has input steps to get XML files. But i need a javascript code which transform this kind of file in a "pure" xml. I mean, i need to transform the html code in xml with javascript.